# Stack and Heap about memory address question

Tags: c++, memory-management, stack, heap-memory

I knew what is stack and heap, but when I did some experiments on this topic, I found something surprising.

```
int i,j;

std::cout<< &i << "\n";
std::cout<< &j << "\n";
```

Results:

```
0x7a893a29e5b8
0x7a893a29e5bc
```

That means stack is toward to high address, and not to low address which is shown by below graph.

[image: from google search]

Comment: Why do you think that your variables should be stored in any particular order?

Comment: From a C++ developer's standpoint, it is irrelevant how automatic and free store are implemented (most of the time). It just so happens an automatic store might be implemented as some sort of a stack. There is also an [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). The compiler is free to do many things. So is the implementation.

Comment: The graph is for teaching purposes. That's not how it is in your modern computer, for example.

Comment: It's quite possible that the compiler generated code that reserves a block of 8 bytes for stack variables and then assigns the addresses for `i` and `j` in order. There's nothing that specifies the order in which stack variables are assigned.

Answer (score 0):

stack and heap both are regions of memory used by computer programs.

**1. Stack:**  A stack is used for storing data related to function calls, local variables, and other execution context information.

**2. Heap:**  heap is used for dynamically allocated memory, such as when a program uses the new or malloc functions to allocate memory at runtime.

Now let's begin with question:

**First check what is memory address ?**

A memory address is a unique identifier that refers to a location in memory where data can be stored or retrieved.

**Stack**:
now we'll check **how the stack work with memory addresses ?**

When we compile a program, the compiler enters through the main function and a stack frame is created on the stack. A structure, also known as an activation record, is the collection of all data on the stack associated with one subprogram call. The main function and all the local variables are stored in an initial frame.

**heap**: **how the heap work with memory addresses ?**

The memory is allocated during the execution of instructions written by programmers. Note that the name heap has nothing to do with the heap data structure. It is called a heap because it is a pile of memory space available to programmers to allocate and de-allocate.