# How does the stack look with malloc?

Tags: c, stack, malloc

I am studying a computer security course, and I am trying to figure out how the stack looks like before reaching the comment line. But the `malloc` is messing me up. I understand how it should look like without the `malloc`. I mean if we only had `char buff[SIZE];` followed by `bool flag = false` then `scanf`, but I can't tell how it looks like here.

The code:

```
#define SIZE 11

int main() {
     char* buff = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char));
     bool* flag = malloc(sizeof(bool));

     *flag = false;
     scanf("%s", buff);

     // random code ...

     return 0; 
}
```

This would be without the malloc:

```
|  Low Addrs   |
+--------------+
|              |
|--------------|
|  flag        |  <- 1 byte
|--------------|
|  buff        |  <- 11 bytes
|--------------|
|  frame ptr   |  <- 4 bytes
|--------------|
|  return addr |  <- 4 bytes
+--------------+
|  High Addrs  |
```

And with the `malloc` I assume something like that ?

```
|  Low Addrs          |
+---------------------+
|                     |
|---------------------|
|  buff               |  <- 11 bytes
|---------------------|
|  flag               |  <- 1 byte
|---------------------|
|  addr flag malloc   |  <- 4 bytes
|---------------------|
|  addr buff malloc   |  <- 4 bytes
|---------------------|
|  frame ptr          |  <- 4 bytes
|---------------------|
|  return addr        |  <- 4 bytes
+---------------------+
|  High Addrs         |
```

However I am not very sure if that is correct. I mean, I know that `malloc` uses the heap and increases the program break pointer to allocate data, so maybe the correct way would be that the 11 bytes and the 1 byte added on top shouldn't be there? and instead the actual data would be in the heap ???
the `malloc` just messed me up :/

***Note: assume no ASLR technology.***

Comment: I'd recommend you to try out godbolt.org. There you'll see exact assembly code generated from C which might give you a clearer picture.

Comment: You correctly state that `malloc` uses the heap, so why do you assume that the data for buff and flag would still be located on the stack? The heap is not part of the stack, so therefore the stack will only hold the pointers but not the actual data. Also, since you only have a handful of variables, even those pointers won't necessarily be stored on the stack (the compiler might just use registers instead, at least when compiling with optimizations)

Comment: Might help if you printed out the addresses and sizes of the variables?

Comment: Important: please note that my comment only applies to the way these things are usually handled on most platforms. Technically the existence of a stack or heap isn't necessary at all, and neither are even mentioned in the standard. So, as far as the standard is concerned, as long as an implementation provides a way to dynamically allocate memory through `malloc`, everything is fine. It is entirely implementation dependent how that is actually done (so, in theory, it could actually happen on the stack)

Comment: @FelixG you were correct, the stack will not hold the actual data variables on the top, so I guess I got my answer. Thank you very much guys for the help, appreciated

Comment: Yes, at least for your particular platform (and probably 99.9% of platforms in use today). But don't forget that all of this is entirely implementation-dependent, so you can't assume that the layout will always look like that. In theory, there could even be an implementation which doesn't use a stack at all, but does everything through the heap.

Comment: How the stack ends up depends entirely on the system used, its stack frame format and ABI, as well as the level of optimization used. For example the calling convention to malloc and scanf are likely take up some stack, depending on ABI. It's very pointless to discuss things like this based on some "generic imaginary system". ASLR doesn't matter for the stack layout.

Comment: A `bool *` doesn't occupy only one byte on the stack. It's a *pointer*. In addition, it's probably wrong to assume that the address of `flag` is lower than the address of `buff`. I'm pretty sure the C standard leaves that detail up to the implementation, so it could vary by compiler. Also, my experience with C in the past indicates that if you have, say, `int a, b;`, then `a` is the lower address. If you use a pointer cast to store a `long long` in `a`, it will probably overwrite whatever value you have in `b`. Of course, you can verify all this by loading the code in your debugger.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/61540247/56778, which indicates that at least one compiler acts as I describe.